# How to array merge as same value?

Tags: arrays

i am using one query but i can't add group by emil so i am use other option but i can't understand how to grouping contact_email with mt4_account_no.

my array mention blow:

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [contact_fullName] => Walt Wuller
            [contact_email] => walt.wuller@ww.in
            [mt4_account_no] => 12291
            [balance] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [contact_fullName] => Walt Wuller
            [contact_email] => walt.wuller@ww.in
            [mt4_account_no] => 12293
            [balance] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [contact_fullName] => Walt Wuller
            [contact_email] => walt.wuller@ww.in
            [mt4_account_no] => 12289
            [balance] => 7480.69
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [contact_fullName] => Walt Wuller
            [contact_email] => walt.wuller@ww.in
            [mt4_account_no] => 12292
            [balance] => 0
        )
```

But i wanna create like this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [contact_fullName] => Walt Wuller
            [contact_email] => walt.wuller@ww.in
            [mt4_account_no] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 12291
                    [1] => 12293
                    [2] => 12289
                    [3] => 12292
                )

            [balance] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 0
                    [2] => 7480.69
                    [3] => 0
                )

        )

)
```

So how i can create this kind of array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $array =array(
        0=> Array
            (
                'contact_fullName' => 'Walt Wuller',
                'contact_email' => 'walt.wuller@ww.in',
                'mt4_account_no' => '12291',
                'balance' => '0',
            ),

        1 => Array
            (
                'contact_fullName' => 'Walt Wuller',
                'contact_email' => 'walt.wuller@ww.in',
                'mt4_account_no' => '12292',
                'balance' => '0',
            ),

        2 => Array
            (
                'contact_fullName' => 'Walt Wuller',
                'contact_email' => 'walt.wuller@ww.in',
                'mt4_account_no' => '12293',
                'balance' => '3434',
            ),

        3 => Array
            (
                'contact_fullName' => 'Walt Wuller',
                'contact_email' => 'walt.wuller@ww.in',
                'mt4_account_no' => '12295',
                'balance' => '0',
            )
        );

    $contact =array();
    $mt4 =array();
    $balance =array();

    foreach ($array as $key => $val)
    {
        $contact[$val['contact_fullName']]= array($val['contact_fullName'], $val['contact_email']) ;
        $mt4[$val['contact_fullName']][] = $val['mt4_account_no'];
        $balance[$val['contact_fullName']][]  = $val['balance'];
    }

    $new_array = array();
    foreach($contact as $key => $value)
    {
        $new_array[] = array(
                'contact_fullName' => $value[0],
                'contact_email' => $value[1],
                'mt4_account_no' => $mt4[$value[0]],
                'balance' => $balance[$value[0]],
        );
    }
    print '<pre>';
    print_r($new_array);
```

Comment: thank you sergiu costas it working fine 
i am vtiger crm developer i any help contact me

Comment: If you like my answer than please select my answer as best answer :)